# No value given for one or more required parameters in Oledb query

Tags: c#, sql, .net, oledb

I'm trying to query a CSV file. It works when I do a simple select, but as soon as I try to add a `where` clause, I run into *No value given for one or more required parameters*.

Obviously, it sounds like it's not getting the supplied parameter, but I've tried to pass it in a number of ways. See below for some code samples

```
DateTime lastRunDate = Convert.ToDateTime(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LastRunDate"]);

OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(
            "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + base.applicationRoot + ";" +
            "Extended Properties=\"text;HDR=Yes;FMT=CSVDelimited\"");

// This works just fine
//OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(String.Format("select * from {0}", 

// This gives the error
OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(String.Format("select top 100 * from [{0}] where {0}.sale_date = @sDate", base.csvFileName), conn);
//adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@sDate", OleDbType.DBDate).Value = lastRunDate;
adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sDate", lastRunDate);

// This also gives the same error as above
//OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(String.Format("select top 100 * from {0} where sale_date = '{1}'", base.csvFileName, lastRunDate), conn);
base.csvFileName, lastRunDate.ToShortDateString()), conn);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
adapter.Fill(dt);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found he issue with this. The query simply didn't understand the column names.

I thought that setting `HDR=Yes` meant that the `oledb` would read the first row headers, hence know them. But it wasn't until I added a `schema.ini` file that I managed to query in this way.

[Here's some more about schema.ini files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I ran into this issue today. The schema.ini file exists. I am importing files with different names each time. I simply forgot to update the schema file with the new filename each time. Check your schema file kids!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about C#, and I'm still decently new to SQL, but perhaps it's the SELECT TOP part of your query. I know that SELECT TOP isn't really accepted on all db systems, and that it's included in both of your queries that are giving you problems. Have you tried removing that and using LIMIT instead?

```
"select top 100 * from [{0}] where {0}.sale_date = @sDate"
```

to

```
"select * from [{0}] where {0}.sale_date = @sDate LIMIT 100"
```

I would have added this as a comment as it's not a concrete answer, but I have not the required rep yet.:(

Comment: Thank you for your input, but I have tried without the top 100 as well.

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line. You have added parameter twice.

```
adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sDate", lastRunDate);
```

and make sure the value is present in `lastRunDate` variable. it should not be null.

**EDITED:**

Remove table name from the where condtion, Use like this

select top 100 * from [{0}] where sale_date=@sDate

Comment: Thanks for your input, but that was a typo on my part. It is just one of the many things I've tried. I  commented out one of the adding of parameters

Comment: @TheJonasPersson I have checked your code and reproduced the bug, I have edited my answer please check.

Comment: Sorry, that still didn't do it for me. But, I've found out what my problem is. The where statement doesn't recognize the column names in the first row. If I change 'sale_date' to 'AI' (the actual column in Excel), it works. So, new question. How do I get the column names? I thought `HDR=Yes` would do the trick.

Comment: @TheJonasPersson Your new question required more information like your csv data format, sql query and what is your requirement. So, I think you should ask a new question separately. So, you can get more answers and replies. Don't forget to point out this question.

Answer (score 1):

Column Names in the Excel file and in the Query are not Same.

1. Either column name is missing.
2. Column Name not existing in the Excel File.